# iPhone 6 Launch Screen Images issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, splash-screen, iphone-6

My app is not support iPhone 6 but it will running nice with scaled mode.
there is no launch image previously.

but now if I try to put launch image for iPhone6 then the view are not displays correctly as previous scaled mode. I used image.assets folder LaunchImage.

I don't know why this is happened?

**Help me to solve this.**

**Thank you**

Comment: You have to set your design according to iphone6 size whether it is with AutoLayout constraint or using any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a Launch Image for iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 plus, they expect you to design the app for both, it won't automatically scale or else you would have used proper autolayout which will adjust the view accordingly.